# Compiler not mapping a class method to an interface method

Tags: delphi, enumeration

I am using Delphi Pro 10.2.3 Tokyo.  I want to create a TDataset wrapper class which I can use to enumerate through a list of IData descendants with a for-in loop.  When I try to compile the code below, I get the following error message.

[dcc32 Error] Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.pas(25): E2291 Missing implementation of interface method IEnumerator.GetCurrent

Clearly, GetCurrent is implemented.  Any idea how to fix this?

```
unit Core.Data.DatasetAdapter;

interface

uses
    Data.Db
  ;

type
  IData = interface
    ['{15D1CF4F-B9E1-4525-B035-24B9A6584325}']
  end;

  IDataList<T: IData> = interface
    ['{9FEE9BB1-A983-4FEA-AEBF-4D3AF5219444}']
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetCurrent: T;
    procedure Load;
    procedure Unload;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Current: T read GetCurrent;
  end;

  TDatasetAdapter<T: IData> = class(
      TInterfacedObject
    , IData, IDataList<T>
    , IEnumerator<T>
  )
  private
    FBof: Boolean;
    FDataset: TDataset;
    FIntf: T;
    function GetCount: Integer;
    function GetCurrent: T;
    function GetEof: Boolean;
    function GetInterface: T;
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
    procedure Reset;
  protected
    function FieldByName(const FieldName: string): TField;
    procedure MapFields; virtual;
    property Dataset: TDataset read FDataset;
  public
    constructor Create(ADataset: TDataset); virtual;
    function GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<T>;
    procedure Cancel;
    procedure Close;
    procedure Delete;
    procedure Edit;
    procedure First;
    procedure Insert;
    procedure Load;
    procedure Next;
    procedure Open;
    procedure Post;
    procedure UnLoad;
    property Count: Integer read GetCount;
    property Eof: Boolean read GetEof;
  end;

implementation

uses

    System.SysUtils
  , System.TypInfo
  ;

{ TDatasetAdapter<T> }

{
****************************** TDatasetAdapter<T> ******************************
}
constructor TDatasetAdapter<T>.Create(ADataset: TDataset);
begin
  FDataset := ADataset;
  FIntf    := GetInterface;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Cancel;
begin
  FDataset.Cancel;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Close;
begin
  FDataset.Close;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Delete;
begin
  FDataset.Delete;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Edit;
begin
  FDataset.Edit;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.FieldByName(const FieldName: string): TField;
begin
  Result := FDataset.FieldByName(FieldName);
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.First;
begin
  FDataset.First;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := FDataset.RecordCount;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.GetCurrent: T;
begin
  Result := FIntf;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<T>;
begin
  Reset;
  Result := Self;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.GetEof: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FDataset.Eof;
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.GetInterface: T;
var
  LGuid: TGuid;
begin
  LGuid := GetTypeData(TypeInfo(T))^.Guid;
  if not Supports(Self, LGuid, Result) then
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Insert;
begin
  FDataset.Insert;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Load;
begin
  Open;
  MapFields;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.MapFields;
begin
  //Stub procedure
end;

function TDatasetAdapter<T>.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  if FBof then FBof := False
  else         Next;
  Result := not Eof;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Next;
begin
  FDataset.Next;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Open;
begin
  FDataset.Open;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Post;
begin
  FDataset.Post;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.Reset;
begin
  FBof := True;
  First;
end;

procedure TDatasetAdapter<T>.UnLoad;
begin
  Close;
end;

end.
```

Comment: I wonder shouldn't the error, instead, say *"Missing implementation of interface method IEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent"*.

Comment: @sertac-akyuz I copied and pasted the message directly from the IDE message frame.

Comment: @Sertac: no, because that one is implemented. Apparently **the one inherited from `IEnumerator` (non generic), returning a `TObject`, is not hidden by the new one returning a `T`**. The one returning a `TObject` must be implemented too. See my answer.

Comment: joeb, yes, I wondered why the compiler complained that when what you implemented was IEnumerator<T>, but thanks to @Rudy, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to resolve `function GetCurrent: T` twice: for `IDataList<T>` and for `Enumerator<T>`. **But you also need one for the non-generic ancestor of `IEnumerator<T>`: `IEnumerator`**. Apparently that is not hidden by the `GetCurrent` method of `IEnumerator<T>`.

Try [method resolution clauses](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Implementing_Interfaces):

```
function GetGenericCurrent: T; // implement this
function IDataList<T>.GetCurrent = GetGenericCurrent;
function IEnumerator<T>.GetCurrent = GetGenericCurrent;
function GetCurrent: TObject; // implement this -- can return nil.
```

The implementation of both can be the same, but you will have to make two methods. The one for the non-generic `IEnumerator` can return `nil`.

---

#### Update

I had to modify the code above. Now it should work. It is not necessary to have two implementations for `GetCurrent` returning `T`, but you must have one returning `TObject`.

Comment: Really. I'd expect a single method and one method resolution clause would suffice.

Comment: @rudy-veltuis  I agree with David.   I renamed IDataList.GetCurrent to IDataList.GetItem AND used a method resolution clause to map IEnumerator.GetCurrent.  Get the same error message.

Comment: Anyway, I modified my answer. I forgot to have a version for non-generic `IEnumerator`.

Comment: That's what the error message says of course. How could we miss that.

Comment: @David: I was not sure if the message distinguished between IEnumerator<T> and IEnumerator. And I even tried with method resolution clauses for non-generic IEnumerator too, but then there would be a different message because IEnumerator was not explicitly part of the implementation list. This is the only way it works.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I coded as you suggested.  The code compiled, but when I attempted to test it in a for-in loop, I got the following error code:  [dcc32 Error] Tests.Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.pas(83): E2431 for-in statement cannot operate on collection type 'Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.IDataList<Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.IData>' because 'Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.IDataList<Core.Data.DatasetAdapter.IData>' does not contain a member for 'GetEnumerator', or it is inaccessible

Comment: @joeb545: that is another question. This one was about IEnumerator.GetCurrent.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I figured it out.  I needed to add GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<T> to IDataList<T>.  Thanks for the solution!